# Stop selecting text on a table element

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code that stops the user selecting text in a table element.

```
$('table').live("selectstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works in IE, but not in Firefox.  How can I get this to work in Firefox?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
if($.browser.mozilla){//Firefox
    $('table').css('MozUserSelect','none');
}else if($.browser.msie){//IE
   $('table').live("selectstart", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
}else{//Opera, etc.
   $('table').mousedown(function(){return false;});
}
```

Or use this plugin:
http://chris-barr.com/entry/disable_text_selection_with_jquery/